# Why isn't the IEnumerable returned from LINQ Where() method wholly consumed by Count()?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I was aware that the `Count()` method supplied by LINQ had an optimization whereby it would check whether the source sequence implemented `ICollection<T>` and if so call the `Count` property rather than iterating over the entire collection. When this optimization is used, the underlying `IEnumerable<T>` is not consumed, so it can be consumed by other calls succeeding `Count()`.

Notably, the overload of Count which accepts a predicate performs no such optimization because it must inspect the value of each element.

Now consider the following complete program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace count_where_issue
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<int> items = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
            IEnumerable<int> evens = items.Where(y => y % 2 == 0);
            int count = evens.Count();
            int first = evens.First();
            Console.WriteLine("count = {0}", count);
            Console.WriteLine("first = {0}", first);
        }
    }
}
```

which prints,

```
count = 3
first = 2
```

My expectation was the Count would need to consume the whole `evens` sequence returned by `Where()` and the subsequent call to `evens.First()` would fail with `InvalidOperationException` because the sequence would contain no elements.

Why does this program work the way it does?  I would not normally attempt to use an `IEnumerable<T>` following a call to `Count(). Would it be unwise to rely on this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `IEnumerator<T>` you would not be able to use.  However, Count and First each create a separate enumerator (via calls to `GetEnumerator` on the `IEnumerable<T>`).

Comment: Presumably, this is only effective because the ultimate source of the data - the List - can be iterated over more than once.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what you mean, but `evens.Count()` and `evens.First()` both enumerate the `items.Where(...)`.

You can see this in the output of the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> items = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        IEnumerable<int> evens = items.Where(y => isEven(y));

        int count = evens.Count();
        Console.WriteLine("count = {0}", count);

        int first = evens.First();
        Console.WriteLine("first = {0}", first);

    }

    private static bool isEven(int y)
    {
        Console.Write(y + ": ");

        bool result = y % 2 == 0;

        Console.WriteLine(result);    
        return result;
    }
}
```

Which is:

```
1: False
2: True
3: False
4: True
5: False
6: True
count = 3
1: False
2: True
first = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever gave you the impression that Count() affects the original IEnumerable in any way?

The docs don't mention anything of the sort...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038.aspx

Comment: I got the impression from reading Jon Skeet's blog posts on the workings of LINQ - particularly this article: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/26/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-7-count-and-longcount.aspx